# More than one buttons in uitableviewcell

Tags: iphone, uitableview, ios6, uibutton

I have to create a cell in which more than one buttons resides. Here tableview is expandable and collapse,number of section and number of row in section is dynamic.

I want task in this manner[image]

that is in each row i want only 4 task n remaining task will display on next row. But my problem is, if i have only 13 task than it contain 4 row, in 1st 2nd and 3rd row it contain 4 tasks and in last row it contain only 1 task but i m not able to that also it text also not change as per task.

Here is my code.

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if ([self tableView:tableView canCollapseSection:section])
    {
        if ([expandedSections containsIndex:section])
        {
            objePro = [appDelegate.array_proj objectAtIndex:section];

            rowcount = [objePro.arr_task count] + 1;
            NSLog(@"rowcount %d",rowcount);
            if (rowcount < 4)
                return 2;
            else
            {
                if (rowcount % 4)
                {
                    NSLog(@"odd: %d",rowcount/4 + 2);
                    return rowcount/4 + 2;
                }
                else
                {
                    NSLog(@"even: %d",rowcount/4);
                    return rowcount/4;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return 1;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] ;
    }
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    if ([self tableView:tableView canCollapseSection:indexPath.section])
    {
        if (!indexPath.row)
        {
            cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
            UIImageView *backgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
            cell.backgroundView = backgroundView;
            backgroundView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"prjctcell_bg.png"];

            objePro = [appDelegate.array_proj objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];

            cell.textLabel.text = objePro.projctname;
            if ([expandedSections containsIndex:indexPath.section])
                cell.accessoryView = [DTCustomColoredAccessory accessoryWithColor:[UIColor blackColor] type:DTCustomColoredAccessoryTypeUp];
            else
                cell.accessoryView = [DTCustomColoredAccessory accessoryWithColor:[UIColor blackColor] type:DTCustomColoredAccessoryTypeDown];
        }
        else
        {
            // all other rows
            cell.accessoryView = nil;

            j=4;

                for (k = 0; k<4; k++)
                {
                    NSLog(@"k %d",k);

                    btnexpand = [[UIButton alloc] init];
                    btnexpand = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
                    btnexpand.frame = CGRectMake(j, 5, 80, 40);
                    btnexpand.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
                    [btnexpand setTitleColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:53.0/255 green:53.0/255 blue:53.0/255 alpha:1.0] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                    btnexpand.titleLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:14];

                    [btnexpand setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Step %d",[[[[appDelegate.array_proj objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] arr_task] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row - 1] taskid]] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                    NSLog(@"btn title: %@",btnexpand.titleLabel.text);

                    [btnexpand setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"greenarrow.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                    [cell.contentView addSubview:btnexpand];

                    j= j+65;
                }

        }
    }
    return cell;
}
```

Please help me.

Comment: @Manohar, i don't want to create a custom cell. Can this things happen without custom cell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `numberOfRowsInSection`

```
rowcount = [objePro.arr_task count]; // Keep original count
if (rowcount % 4) // This means its not exact multiple of four
    return rowcount/4 + 2;
else
    return rowcount + 1;
```

In cellForRowAtIndexPath

```
if(indexpath.row == 0){
    Your code for header line
}
else{
    objePro = [appDelegate.array_proj objectAtIndex:section];
    int rowcount = [objePro.arr_task count];
    if(rowcount < 4){
         for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
                 NSLog (@"%d", i+1);
         }
    }
    else{
         int iRow = rowcount / 4;
         if (rowcount % 4){
              for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
                   NSLog(@"Current Step %d", indexpath.row-1 + i);
         }
         else{
              for(int i = 0; i < rowcount % 4; i++)
                   NSLog(@"Current Step %d", indexpath.row-1 + i);
         }

    }



}
```

This is all trick, you need to put some efforts. Hope I have shown you some direction.

Comment: That was i :( I misprinted